# Combining list elements into one element in python

Tags: python, list, merge, element

I have a list in Python that looks like this:

```
Temp = ['H,test,0,04/09/2014,15:19:35,15:28:30,0.07,0,0,avo,1', 'N,2,1,240.00,30.00,1,3,1,,,,,,,', 'K,0.18,,,,', 'D,,,,,,,,,15,', 'U,35P019,000000,ST,5,U,00,Y,0000,,', 'T,1,Disk,WH,All Element,FL,72,0.062,0.079,0.070,PASS']
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
Temp = ['H','test','0','04/09/2014','15:19:35','15:28:30','0.07','0','0','avo','1','N','2','1','240.00','30.00','1','3','1','','','','','','','', 'K','0.18','','','','','D','','','','','','','','','15','','U','35P019','000000','ST','5','U','00','Y','0000','','','T','1','Disk','WH','All Element','FL','72','0.062','0.079','0.070','PASS']
```

How can this be done?  How can all elements be combined to one element?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want the end result to be a 1-element list rather than just a string? There are valid uses for a 1-element list, but here, it seems better to just use the string.

Comment: You're right...I made a mistake in my original post!  Please see the update.  Sorry to those who answered what was a rather foolish question!

Comment: So you don't actually want to merge the strings; you want to *split* them on commas and merge the resulting lists. (I suspect it'd actually be more useful to split on commas and then *not* merge, so you have a list of lists of strings.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your latest edit, you need to split the list based on `,`, so you can do

```
print [item for items in Temp for item in items.split(",")]
```

**Output**

```
['H',
 'test',
 '0',
 '04/09/2014',
 '15:19:35',
 '15:28:30',
 '0.07',
 '0',
 '0',
 'avo',
 '1',
 'N',
 '2',
 '1',
 '240.00',
 '30.00',
 '1',
 '3',
 '1',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'K',
 '0.18',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'D',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '15',
 '',
 'U',
 '35P019',
 '000000',
 'ST',
 '5',
 'U',
 '00',
 'Y',
 '0000',
 '',
 '',
 'T',
 '1',
 'Disk',
 'WH',
 'All Element',
 'FL',
 '72',
 '0.062',
 '0.079',
 '0.070',
 'PASS']
```

**Note:** According to [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), Python Style Bible, using a variable name with an initial capital letter is not encouraged.

Comment: Please see my comment @mhlester

Comment: have at it @thefourtheye :)

Comment: @mhlester Anyway, OPs edit completely changed the meaning of the question :(

Comment: Almost...Notice how, for instance, the second element 'test' is split into 4 elements 't' 'e' 's' 't' ['H', '', '', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '', '', '0', '', '', '0', '4', '/', '0', '9', '/', '2', '0', '1', '4', '', '', '1', '5', ':', '1', '9', ':', '3', '5', '', '', '1', '5', ':', '2', '8', ':', '3', '0', '', '', '0', '.', '0', '7', '', '', '0', '', '', '0', '', '', 'a', 'v', 'o', '', '', '1', '', '', 'N', '', '', '2', '', '', '1', '', '', '2', '4', '0', '.', '0', '0', '', '', '3', '0', '.', '0', '0', '', '', '1', '', '', '3', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',

Comment: @BrocolliRob Please check the output I got

Comment: Oh, my mistake...I was passing it a string, not a list.  Thank you!  And thanks to @mhlester too!